# JavaScript Equivalent Of PHP __invoke

Tags: javascript, php, class

I'm developing a small framework (in JS) and for esthetic reasons and simplicity I was wondering if there could be a way to implement something like PHP "__invoke".

For example:

```
var myClass = function(config) {
    this.config = config;
    this.method = function(){};
    this.execute = function() {
        return this.method.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
var execCustom = new myClass({ wait: 100 });
execCustom.method = function() {
    console.log("called method with "+arguments.length+" argument(s):");
    for(var a in arguments) console.log(arguments[a]);
    return true;
};
execCustom.execute("someval","other");
```

Desired way to execute:

```
execCustom("someval","other");
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ESOLIce/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Not as far as I know, because execCustom is an instance of the function myClass, so you either use the main function as a constructor for the class, or as a method to execute. The only thing I can think of would be to define a wrapper function, something like function exec(execCustom){execCustom.__invoke()} where __invoke is defined as a function in execCustom (myClass).

Comment: Thanks Zack. Yes, I thought so... If I don't find a prettier way to do it, then I think I will leave it like that.

Comment: Its ugly as hell, but your other option would be to do an if() in the constructor to check that config is an array. If so, continue, else call the method __invoke. But, that assumes that you will never want to pass an array to the __invoke method, and that you will always want to pass one to the constructor (its also just plain nasty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are ready to use JS pattern, you can do this in following way:

```
var myClass = function(opts) {
          return function(){
            this.config = opts.config;
            this.method = opts.method;
            return this.method.apply(this, arguments);
          };
        };


var execCustom = new myClass({
        config:{ wait: 100 }, 
        method:function() {
            console.log("called method with "+arguments.length+" argument(s):");
            for(var a in arguments) console.log(arguments[a]);
            return true;
        }});

execCustom("someval","other");
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ESOLIce/11/watch?js,console)

this is the best way I can think of

**UPDATED VERSION** (by op)

```
var myClass = function(opts) {
      var x = function(){
          return x.method.apply(x, arguments);
      };
      x.config = opts.config;
      x.method = opts.method;
      return x; 
    };


var execCustom = new myClass({
    config:{ wait: 100 }, 
    method:function() {
        console.log("called method with "+arguments.length+" argument(s):");
        for(var a in arguments) console.log(arguments[a]);
        return true;
    }});

execCustom("someval","other");
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ESOLIce/13/watch?js,console)

Comment: Very creative! I guess it is no longer possible to access to "config" and "method" values anymore?

Comment: I updated your code in order to have access to the properties: http://jsbin.com/ESOLIce/13/watch?js,console
Do you see any problem with that code?

Comment: in my code,console.log(execCustom instanceof myClass)//false. you should notice this, execCustom is not myClass instance.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that difference. Still the code is useful. Thanks!

Comment: in your code, you are creating a new object and return that object, so the object you return although it has original config and method, but it is not instance of MyClass as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just return a function that will form the public interface:

```
function myClass(config)
{
  var pubif = function() {
    return pubif.method.apply(pubif, arguments);
  };
  pubif.config = config;
  pubif.method = function() { };

  return pubif;
}
```

The rest of the code remains the same.